# Getting email address from the contact details

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

Im trying to open the MailComposeViewController from the contacts details using swift. Everything works fine, when I click the contact's email, the page opens, but i would like to populate the recipient email field with the email i just clicked, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
 func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self

        //This doesn't work, only asks for a string. 
        mail.setToRecipients(["\(contactProperty.value)"])


        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {() -> Void in
            self.presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

    } else {
        print("send error")
    }
}
```

I can only add strings to mail.setToRecipients. When I use contactProperty.value, it gives me this error:

Optional(example@email.com) is not a valid email address.

Comment: Use 'as' to the address ... Mean unwrap it before assigning

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry, just new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CNContactProperty.value` is of type `AnyObject?` which means it's an optional.
So you need to safely unwrap it and cast it as string.

Try replacing this

```
mail.setToRecipients(["\(contactProperty.value)"])
```

with

```
if let emailAddress = contactProperty.value as? String {
        mail.setToRecipients([emailAddress])
    }
```